# eth.isSyncing command not working

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am running geth with this command : `geth --syncmode "fast" --cache 2048 --rpc --datadir /media/username/2TB_HDD` and then in new terminal I typed : `geth attach ipc://media/username/2TB_HDD/geth.ipc` command. After that when I typed eth.isSyncing then i am getting this :
 `> eth.isSyncing
   function(callback)`

Why I am not getting the blocks data like before like currentBlock, highest block?

Comment: Use `eth.syncing`

Comment: In future if you forget you can just type `eth` into the console and geth will list the potential functions (likewise if you type net, admin or personal you'll see the relevant functions for each)

Comment: Can you guys tell me how can i know if blockchain is synced ? when i use this command to check : eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5046087,
  highestBlock: 5046261,
  knownStates: 753,
  pulledStates: 309,
  startingBlock: 5045742
}
Then the highest block keep increasing then how can i know if blockchain is synced ? because of this i am getting web3.eth.getBlock('latest') block as 0.